# Parsing through HTML with beautiful soup and python: working with table data

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'm trying to parse the data stored as different tables from the following website:

https://teams.technion.ac.il/residency-placements/

I want to parse the data from the table and store it as a dataframe. I'm trying my hand at beautifulsoup. I've already figured out which id tag to parse on and have found that there are ten separate ones (eg tab-1, tab-2,...,tab-10). I want to write a function that will loop through the HTML and store the text under each tab as a separate dataframe in pandas. I'm a beginner at this so I have no idea what I'm doing. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this is not a code-writing or tutorial service, and we ask that you provide a [mcve] including code for what you've already tried based on your own research. Your best bet would be to find a tutorial or other resource, try some things, and then come back and ask specific questions if you hit specific problems. As-is, this question is likely to be closed as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for being too broad

Answer (score 0):

I found [lxml](https://lxml.de/) to be very helpful when looping through HTML to parse/gather/store data. Do some research on using xpath to loop through, you can easily grab all of the text and store it using this method:

```
    from lxml import etree

    root = etree.HTML(html)
    textOut = root.xpath('//*[text()]') #grab all text OR
    textOut = root.xpath('//*[text()[contains(., "stuff")]]') #grab just text you want
```

Given the site you noted and that you're scraping tables, you can use xpath to direct your searches to tables only like this:

```
    textOut = root.xpath('//table[text()]') #grab just text from tables
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to grab a table, and use whichtable to choose which one, as there are multiple:

```
def getContent(link, filename, whichtable=0):
    result1 = requests.get(link)
    src1 = result1.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src1,'lxml')
    table = soup.find_all('table')[whichtable]
    with open(filename,'w',newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for tr in table('tr'):
            row = [t.get_text(strip=True)for t in tr(['td','th'])]
            writer.writerow(row)
getContent('https://teams.technion.ac.il/residency-placements/', 'what.csv', whichtable=0)
df2= pd.read_csv('what.csv')
```

output:

```
                                    Hospital/Location                                  Specialty
0          Maimonides Med Ctr-NYMaimonides Med Ctr-NY         Medicine-PreliminaryAnesthesiology
1                          Jacobi Med Ctr/Einstein-NY                                 Pediatrics
2                          Jacobi Med Ctr/Einstein-NY                                 Pediatrics
3                                 Temple Univ Hosp-PA                          Internal Medicine
4                 Case Western/MetroHealth Med Ctr-OH                                 Pediatrics
5                      Sinai Hospital of Baltimore-MD                                 Pediatrics
6                                 Baystate Med Ctr-MA                                   Medicine
7                      U Rochester/Strong Memorial-NY                             Anesthesiology
8                               Johns Hopkins Hosp-MD                        Surgery-Preliminary
9                          Westchester Medical Ctr-NY                                 Psychiatry
10                                Danbury Hospital-CT                                   Medicine
11                        Icahn SOM at Mount Sinai-NY                                 Pediatrics
12                 Emory Univ SOM-GAEmory Univ SOM-GA                    TransitionalDermatology
13  NYMC-Metropolitan Hosp Ctr-NYKingsbrook Jewish...  Medicine-PreliminaryPhys Medicine & Rehab
14                            Advocate Health Care-IL                            Pediatrics/ALGH
15                                    Mayo Clinic- WI                            Family Medicine
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to extract data from tables, too. Other things need to be dealt with by yourself.
First, you need to install libs using pip

```
pip install requests
pip install simplified_scrapy
```

---

```
import requests
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
html=requests.get('https://teams.technion.ac.il/residency-placements/').text
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
tables = doc.getElementsByClass('entry',start='listitems') # Use start to filter previous div
data = []
for table in tables:
  t=[] # Data of a table
  rows = table.trs # get all rows
  for row in rows:
    tds = row.children # get all td and th
    t.append([td.text for td in tds])
  data.append(t)

print (data)
```